# How to solve this minimum steps needed to reach end of matrix problem?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Given a matrix containing initial state of each elements, find minimum number of steps to reach from top left to bottom right?

Conditions:

Initial state of any element will be randomly one of North, East, South or West.
At every step, we can either not move anywhere or move in the direction of current state of that element (ofcourse we never go out of the matrix)
Any step will simulatanously change the state of all elements of the matrix. States change in a clockwise cyclic manner i.e from N -> E -> S -> W. Even if we don't move in a step, the states do change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important observation is that the matrix has 4 different "versions": Every multiple of 4 steps, the contents of the matrix will be exactly the same.

You could imagine those 4 matrices as a third dimension (Z-direction), where Z can be 0, 1, 2 or 3. Imagine it as a 3D array with the 4 x 2D arrays layered behind each-other.

With that 3D matrix, the magic of the "turning" values disappears: each of those 4 matrices is now static.

A step is now either:

- a move following the direction as indicated by the content at the current cell, so X or Y changes, or
- a move where X and Y remain unchanged

...but in both cases Z becomes (Z+1)%4

The target cell is now actually a set of 4 cells, as it does not matter what Z is at the moment you arrive in the bottom-right corner.

If you build this (unweighted, directed) graph, you can implement a simple BFS search. Problem solved.

### Implementation

I thought I would make a little animation for the following sample input matrix:

```
[
    [2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3],
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
    [3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0],
]
```

The numbers represent the currently possible direction: 0 = North, 1 = East, 2 = South, 3 = West.

The algorithm consists of two functions. One is a method of a Node class, `shortestPathTo`, which implements a generic BFS search from a node to a set of target nodes. A second function, `createGraph`, will convert the input matrix to a graph as described above. After this graph is created, the `shortestPathTo` method can be called on the top-left node. It returns a `path`, an array of nodes to visit.

That path is used to make the animation, which is what the bottom half of the code takes care of. That part has little to do with the algorithm, so you may ignore it.

```js
class Node { // Generic Node class; not dependent on specific problem
    constructor(value, label) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
        this.neighbors = [];
    }
    addEdgeTo(neighbor) {
        this.neighbors.push(neighbor);
    }
    shortestPathTo(targets) {
        targets = new Set(targets); // convert Array to Set
        // Standard BFS
        let queue = [this]; // Start at current node
        let comingFrom = new Map;
        comingFrom.set(this, null);
        while (queue.length) {
            let node = queue.shift();
            if (targets.has(node)) { // Found!
                let path = []; // Build path from back-linked list
                while (node) {
                    path.push(node);
                    node = comingFrom.get(node);
                }
                return path.reverse();
            }
            for (let nextNode of node.neighbors) {
                if (!comingFrom.has(nextNode)) {
                    comingFrom.set(nextNode, node);
                    queue.push(nextNode);
                }
            }
        }
        return []; // Could not reach target node
    }
}

function createGraph(matrix) {
    // Convert the matrix and its move-rules into a directed graph
    const numCols = matrix[0].length;
    const numRows = matrix.length;
    const numNodes = numRows * numCols * 4; // |Y| * |X| * |Z|
    // Create the nodes
    const nodes = [];
    for (let y = 0; y < numRows; y++) 
        for (let x = 0; x < numCols; x++) 
            for (let z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
                let dir = (matrix[y][x] + z) % 4;
                nodes.push(new Node({x, y, z, dir}, "<" + x + "," + y + ":" + "NESW"[dir] + ">"));
            }
    // Create the edges
    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        let node = nodes[i];
        let {x, y, z, dir} = node.value;
        // The "stand-still" neighbor:
        let j = i-z + (z+1)%4;
        node.addEdgeTo(nodes[j]);
        // The neighbor as determined by the node's "direction"
        let dj = 0;
        if      (dir == 0 && y   > 0      ) dj = -numCols*4;
        else if (dir == 1 && x+1 < numCols) dj = 4;
        else if (dir == 2 && y+1 < numRows) dj = numCols*4;
        else if (dir == 3 && x   > 0      ) dj = -4;
        if (dj) node.addEdgeTo(nodes[j+dj]);
    }
    // return the nodes of the graph
    return nodes;
}

// Sample matrix
let matrix = [
    [2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3],
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
    [3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0],
];

// Calculate solution:
const nodes = createGraph(matrix);
const path = nodes[0].shortestPathTo(nodes.slice(-4));
// path now has the sequence of nodes to visit.

// I/O handling for this snippet
const size = 26;
const paint = () => new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve));

function drawSquare(ctx, x, y, angle) {
    ctx.rect(x*size+0.5, y*size+0.5, size, size);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    angle = (270 + angle) * Math.PI / 180;
    x = (x+0.5)*size;
    y = (y+0.5)*size;
    ctx.moveTo(x + 0.5, y + 0.5);
    ctx.lineTo(x + Math.cos(angle) * size * 0.4 + 0.5, y + Math.sin(angle) * size * 0.4 + 0.5);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawBall(ctx, x, y) {
    x = (x+0.5)*size;
    y = (y+0.5)*size;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, size * 0.2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill();
}

async function draw(ctx, matrix, time=0, angle=0, curX=0, curY=0) {
    await paint();
    time = time % 4;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    for (let y = 0; y < matrix.length; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < matrix[0].length; x++) {
            drawSquare(ctx, x, y, (matrix[y][x] + time) * 360 / 4 - angle);
        }
    }
    drawBall(ctx, curX, curY);
}

async function step(ctx, matrix, time, curX, curY, toX, toY) {
    for (let move = 100; move >= 0; move-=5) {
        await draw(ctx, matrix, time, 90, toX + (curX-toX)*move/100, toY + (curY-toY)*move/100);
    }
    for (let angle = 90; angle >= 0; angle-=5) {
        await draw(ctx, matrix, time, angle, toX, toY);
    }
}

async function animatePath(ctx, path) {
    for (let time = 1; time < path.length; time++) {    
        await step(ctx, matrix, time, path[time-1].value.x, path[time-1].value.y, path[time].value.x, path[time].value.y);
    }
}

const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
draw(ctx, matrix);
document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => animatePath(ctx, path);
```

```html
<button>Start</button><br>
<canvas width="400" height="160"></canvas>
```

You can change the definition of `matrix` in the code to try other inputs.